# HiBench wordcount job hangs on hadoop 2.9

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am using:

- HiBench 7.0
- Hadoop 2.9
- Java version 1.8.0_161
- Scala code runner version 2.11.6
- Apache Maven 3.5.2

All on a three-node Hadoop cluster of OpenStack VM's with details:

- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- VCPUs: 8
- RAM: 16GB
- Size: 10GB

Each has a 100GB volume attached where the dfs storage is kept

---

When trying to run wordcount prepare script I am stuck at:

```
hadoop@hadoop0:~/HiBench$ /home/hadoop/HiBench/bin/workloads/micro/wordcount/prepare/prepare.sh
patching args=
Parsing conf: /home/hadoop/HiBench/conf/hadoop.conf
Parsing conf: /home/hadoop/HiBench/conf/hibench.conf
Parsing conf: /home/hadoop/HiBench/conf/workloads/micro/wordcount.conf
probe sleep jar: /home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.9.0-tests.jar
start HadoopPrepareWordcount bench
hdfs rm -r: /home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hadoop --config /home/hadoop/hadoop/etc/hadoop fs -rm -r -skipTrash hdfs://node-master:9000/HiBench/Wordcount/Input
rm: 'hdfs://node-master:9000/HiBench/Wordcount/Input': No such file or directory
Submit MapReduce Job: /home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hadoop --config /home/hadoop/hadoop/etc/hadoop jar /home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.9.0.jar randomtextwriter -D mapreduce.randomtextwriter.totalbytes=32000 -D mapreduce.randomtextwriter.bytespermap=4000 -D mapreduce.job.maps=8 -D mapreduce.job.reduces=8 hdfs://node-master:9000/HiBench/Wordcount/Input
18/02/21 04:03:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1519185680180_0001
```

---

This is a well-known bug, yet the solutions are for problems I don't have:

1. Bad YARN and MapReduce configurations leading to insufficent resources for container allocation, but my configuration files should be set properly in order to prevent this.
2. Insufficient disk space, but as shown I have in excess of 200GB in my hdfs, more than sufficient for a simple wordcount job.

Is this a HiBench issue? Are there minimum resource requirements for HiBench wordcount that I am not satisfying?

#### Below is the output of a few reports while the job is hanging:

```
hadoop@hadoop0:~$ yarn node -list    
18/02/21 04:03:33 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at node-master/10.10.10.7:8032
Total Nodes:3
         Node-Id         Node-State Node-Http-Address   Number-of-Running-Containers
31-24-168.neu.massopencloud.org:34500           RUNNING 31-24-168.neu.massopencloud.org:8042                               0
31-24-168.neu.massopencloud.org:39297           RUNNING 31-24-168.neu.massopencloud.org:8042                               0
31-24-168.neu.massopencloud.org:43353           RUNNING 31-24-168.neu.massopencloud.org:8042                               1

hadoop@hadoop0:~$ yarn application -list    
18/02/21 04:04:05 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at node-master/10.10.10.7:8032
Total number of applications (application-types: [], states: [SUBMITTED, ACCEPTED, RUNNING] and tags: []):1
                Application-Id      Application-Name        Application-Type          User       Queue               State         Final-State         Progress                        Tracking-URL
application_1519185680180_0001    random-text-writer               MAPREDUCE        hadoop     default            ACCEPTED           UNDEFINED               0%                                 N/A


hadoop@hadoop0:~$ hdfs dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 316665593856 (294.92 GB)
Present Capacity: 300320362240 (279.70 GB)
DFS Remaining: 300319195136 (279.69 GB)
DFS Used: 1167104 (1.11 MB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
Under replicated blocks: 2
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
Pending deletion blocks: 0

Live datanodes (3):

Name: 10.10.10.10:50010 (node1)
Hostname: 31-24-168.neu.massopencloud.org
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 105555197952 (98.31 GB)
DFS Used: 331302 (323.54 KB)
Non DFS Used: 62558682 (59.66 MB)
DFS Remaining: 100106821632 (93.23 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 94.84%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Wed Feb 21 04:04:30 UTC 2018
Last Block Report: Wed Feb 21 03:59:45 UTC 2018


Name: 10.10.10.11:50010 (node2)
Hostname: 31-24-168.neu.massopencloud.org
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 105555197952 (98.31 GB)
DFS Used: 331302 (323.54 KB)
Non DFS Used: 62554586 (59.66 MB)
DFS Remaining: 100106825728 (93.23 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 94.84%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Wed Feb 21 04:04:30 UTC 2018
Last Block Report: Wed Feb 21 03:59:45 UTC 2018


Name: 10.10.10.7:50010 (localhost)
Hostname: 31-24-168.neu.massopencloud.org
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 105555197952 (98.31 GB)
DFS Used: 504500 (492.68 KB)
Non DFS Used: 63659340 (60.71 MB)
DFS Remaining: 100105547776 (93.23 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 94.84%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Wed Feb 21 04:04:30 UTC 2018
Last Block Report: Wed Feb 21 03:59:45 UTC 2018
```

#### My yarn-site.xml is as below:

```html
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
            <value>0</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
            <value>node-master</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
            <value>14392</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
            <value>8</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
            <value>1024</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
            <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>2048</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

#### My mapred-site.xml is:

```html
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
        <value>1024</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name>
        <value>-Xmx768m</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
        <description>Execution framework.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores</name>
        <value>1</value>
        <description>The number of virtual cores required for each map task.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores</name>
        <value>1</value>
        <description>The number of virtual cores required for each reduce task.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
        <value>1024</value>
        <description>Larger resource limit for maps.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
        <value>-Xmx768m</value>
        <description>Heap-size for child jvms of maps.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
        <value>1024</value>
        <description>Larger resource limit for reduces.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
        <value>-Xmx768m</value>
        <description>Heap-size for child jvms of reduces.</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Thank you very much for your help.